# Downloading old Safari point releases (Ex: 8.0.4)

Tags: macos, safari, vmware

I am attempting to build VMware Fusion images with each recent point release of Safari. I've had success with the versions bundled with OS X updates (10.10.1, 10.10.2) but I am not sure if it's possible to download a point release that has been superseded by a release in an OS X update. I've found version history with knowledge base documents for each version, but haven't found a way to download them. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history

Example:

- 10.10 shipped with Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25)
- 10.10.1 had Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25.1)
- Safari 8.0.1 and 8.0.2 were in security updates - KB HT204421 and HT204424
- 10.10.2 had Safari 8.0.3 (10600.3.18)
- Safari 8.0.4 was in a security update - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204560
- 10.10.3 has Safari 8.0.5 (10600.5.17)

Comment: Have you found out anything new in the meantime?

Comment: I was able to find some installers here: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15675/apple-safari

Answer (score 1):

Check [oldapps.com](http://www.oldapps.com/mac/safari.php) and [oldversion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/safari/). Be careful with these downloads, I haven't had an issues yet but install at your own risk.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't seem to have download links for any recent versions of Safari.